Manage current window in Incognito Mode? Chrome API
I'm making a chrome extension that opens an incognito window/tab from background, opens a website, and executes some script in the page, but the window object returned is always null no matter what I do:
function createWindow() {
    chrome.windows.create({ 
        incognito:true
    }, (window) => {
        console.log('New window created:', window);
    });
}

// Output: New window created: null

The object ALWAYS returns null.
How am I supossed to interact with the incognito window content?

It depends on what specifically you want to do with the content and what's opened in the window (a website or a dummy page generated by your extension).

I don't think it matters, the window always returns null so I can't do ANYTHING with it.
But it opens a website, and I need the window object so I can execute some code in the opened tab

Sounds like a bug in Chrome then.
